# How used consoled log to ajax param?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sinatra

Im trying to use this console log

```
$.post("greeting", { salutation: console.log(5 + 6), name: "Friend" },
```

to ajax param salutation but not works

How i could solve this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post("greeting", { salutation: console.log(5 + 6), name: "Friend" },
          function(result) { $("#greeting").html(result);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sinatra Ajax Demo using jQuery</h1>
    <div id="greeting">
      <p>Hello, World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me

Also Im using sinatra ruby and not print the 11

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'pp'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end

post '/greeting' do
  #puts "params"
  #pp params

  "<p>#{params[:salutation]}, #{params[:name]}</p>"
end
```

Comment: Your code work just fine for me. Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/q3ebh98p/

Comment: Hi i tested with sinatra ruby and not print the 11 from console 5+6

Comment: `salutation: console.log(5 + 6)` results in a) 11 logged to console, and b) salutation set to `undefined` ... is that what you expect?

Comment: Not I expected 11 but I dont know what is doing wrong

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: if you want salutation set to 11, you would simply put `salutation: 5 + 6` - or even more simply `salutation: 11`

Comment: yes, you get undefined because console.log returns undefined regardless of what it outputs to the debugging console!

Comment: not exist any way to debug the console I need extract data from console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var param = { salutation: 5+6, name: "Friend" };
        $.post("greeting", param, function(result) { 
          console.log("param",param);
          $("#greeting").html(result);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sinatra Ajax Demo using jQuery</h1>
    <div id="greeting">
      <p>Hello, World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```